# Merge multiple lines from for loop into one list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

I have a JSON file my script reads and parses:

```
{
"messages": 
[
    {"timestamp": "123456789", "timestampIso": "2019-06-26 09:51:00", "agentId": "2001-100001", "skillId": "2001-20000", "agentText": "That customer was great"},
    {"timestamp": "123456789", "timestampIso": "2019-06-26 09:55:00", "agentId": "2001-100001", "skillId": "2001-20001", "agentText": "That customer was stupid\nI hope they don't phone back"},
    {"timestamp": "123456789", "timestampIso": "2019-06-26 09:57:00", "agentId": "2001-100001", "skillId": "2001-20002", "agentText": "Line number 3"},
    {"timestamp": "123456789", "timestampIso": "2019-06-26 09:59:00", "agentId": "2001-100001", "skillId": "2001-20003", "agentText": ""}
]
}
```

I have a Python script that strips out the 'agentText' and the for loop prints out each object line by line:

```
import json

with open('20190626-101200-text-messages.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)

for message in data['messages']:
    splittext= message['agentText'].strip().replace('\n',' ').replace('\r',' ')
    if len(splittext) > 0:
       print(splittext)
```

which gives me:

```
That customer was great
That customer was stupid I hope they don't phone back
Line number 3
```

I need to append these separate lines together so it just reads:

```
That customer was great That customer was stupid I hope they don't phone back Line number 3
```

So I can apply some stop words/nltk to it. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could concatenate all rows to a single string variable:

```py
res = ""
for message in data['messages']:
    splittext= message['agentText'].strip().replace('\n',' ').replace('\r',' ')
    if len(splittext)>0:
       res += splittext + " "
```

Or alterantively use string methods with the help of a list:

```py
res = []
for message in data['messages']:
    splittext= message['agentText'].strip().replace('\n',' ').replace('\r',' ')
    if len(splittext)>0:
       res.append(splittext)
print(" ".join(res))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a comprehension with `str.join` and `str.splitlines`

**Ex:**

```
data = {
"messages": 
[
    {"timestamp": "123456789", "timestampIso": "2019-06-26 09:51:00", "agentId": "2001-100001", "skillId": "2001-20000", "agentText": "That customer was great"},
    {"timestamp": "123456789", "timestampIso": "2019-06-26 09:55:00", "agentId": "2001-100001", "skillId": "2001-20001", "agentText": "That customer was stupid\nI hope they don't phone back"},
    {"timestamp": "123456789", "timestampIso": "2019-06-26 09:57:00", "agentId": "2001-100001", "skillId": "2001-20002", "agentText": "Line number 3"},
    {"timestamp": "123456789", "timestampIso": "2019-06-26 09:59:00", "agentId": "2001-100001", "skillId": "2001-20003", "agentText": ""}
]
}

print(" ".join(j for msg in data["messages"] for j in msg["agentText"].splitlines()))
```

**Output:**

```
That customer was great That customer was stupid I hope they don't phone back Line number 3
```